# Quickbook web connector not sending new customer to my website

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I want to  exchange data(customer,invoice,order etc) between Quickbook Desktop and my website using REST API . I am using quickbook web connector and  Consolibyte PHP SDK (https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php) for this purpose. I have installed  web connector and configured PHP SDK also load example.qwc in web connector with my configuration.

Now I am able to create new customer to Quickbook Desktop when new customer is added to my website using this file and folder of PHP SDK(quickbooks-php/docs/web_connector). This is working fine Now I am looking for whenever new record(customer,invoice etc) is created on Quickbook Desktop that should be created on my website.How can I send this data to my website

Issues:

1. Is web connector automatically maintain two way communication or I need to write some PHP Soap web services code to read data from quickbook desktop.
2. How I know new customer,invoice, order is created on Quick book Desktop.and then how can I send this new data to my website.

Answer (score 1):

> 1.Is web connector automatically maintain two way communication

The Web Connector does not automatically do ANYTHING.

Anything you want to happen, you need to write code for. The SDK handles a lot of the hard protocol stuff for you, but you still need to write some code.

> 2.How I know new customer,invoice, order is created on Quick book Desktop

You need to query QuickBooks for that data. There are examples that show you how to do this:

https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/web_connector/example_web_connector_import.php

Basically, you're going to:

**1. Add something new to your `$map` variable:**

```
`QUICKBOOKS_IMPORT_INVOICE => array( '_quickbooks_invoice_import_request', '_quickbooks_invoice_import_response' ),`
```

**2. Write those two new functions that the `$map` variable references.**

The request function is going to return a `qbXML` request to query for new invoices, and the response function is going to handle the big list of new invoices that QuickBooks returns to you (in the example below, it stores them in a MySQL database):

```
/**
 * Build a request to import invoices already in QuickBooks into our application
 */
function _quickbooks_invoice_import_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
{
    // Iterator support (break the result set into small chunks)
    $attr_iteratorID = '';
    $attr_iterator = ' iterator="Start" ';
    if (empty($extra['iteratorID']))
    {
        // This is the first request in a new batch
        $last = _quickbooks_get_last_run($user, $action);
        _quickbooks_set_last_run($user, $action);           // Update the last run time to NOW()

        // Set the current run to $last
        _quickbooks_set_current_run($user, $action, $last);
    }
    else
    {
        // This is a continuation of a batch
        $attr_iteratorID = ' iteratorID="' . $extra['iteratorID'] . '" ';
        $attr_iterator = ' iterator="Continue" ';

        $last = _quickbooks_get_current_run($user, $action);
    }

    // Build the request
    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <?qbxml version="' . $version . '"?>
        <QBXML>
            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                <InvoiceQueryRq ' . $attr_iterator . ' ' . $attr_iteratorID . ' requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                    <MaxReturned>' . QB_QUICKBOOKS_MAX_RETURNED . '</MaxReturned>
                    <ModifiedDateRangeFilter>
                        <FromModifiedDate>' . $last . '</FromModifiedDate>
                    </ModifiedDateRangeFilter>
                    <IncludeLineItems>true</IncludeLineItems>
                    <OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
                </InvoiceQueryRq>   
            </QBXMLMsgsRq>
        </QBXML>';

    return $xml;
}
/** 
 * Handle a response from QuickBooks 
 */
function _quickbooks_invoice_import_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents)
{   
    if (!empty($idents['iteratorRemainingCount']))
    {
        // Queue up another request

        $Queue = QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue_Singleton::getInstance();
        $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_IMPORT_INVOICE, null, QB_PRIORITY_INVOICE, array( 'iteratorID' => $idents['iteratorID'] ));
    }

    // This piece of the response from QuickBooks is now stored in $xml. You 
    //  can process the qbXML response in $xml in any way you like. Save it to 
    //  a file, stuff it in a database, parse it and stuff the records in a 
    //  database, etc. etc. etc. 
    //  
    // The following example shows how to use the built-in XML parser to parse 
    //  the response and stuff it into a database. 

    // Import all of the records
    $errnum = 0;
    $errmsg = '';
    $Parser = new QuickBooks_XML_Parser($xml);
    if ($Doc = $Parser->parse($errnum, $errmsg))
    {
        $Root = $Doc->getRoot();
        $List = $Root->getChildAt('QBXML/QBXMLMsgsRs/InvoiceQueryRs');

        foreach ($List->children() as $Invoice)
        {
            $arr = array(
                'TxnID' => $Invoice->getChildDataAt('InvoiceRet TxnID'),
                'TimeCreated' => $Invoice->getChildDataAt('InvoiceRet TimeCreated'),
                'TimeModified' => $Invoice->getChildDataAt('InvoiceRet TimeModified'),
                'RefNumber' => $Invoice->getChildDataAt('InvoiceRet RefNumber'),
                'Customer_ListID' => $Invoice->getChildDataAt('InvoiceRet CustomerRef ListID'),
                'Customer_FullName' => $Invoice->getChildDataAt('InvoiceRet CustomerRef FullName'),
                'ShipAddress_Addr1' => $Invoice->getChildDataAt('InvoiceRet ShipAddress Addr1'),
                'ShipAddress_Addr2' => $Invoice->getChildDataAt('InvoiceRet ShipAddress Addr2'),
                'ShipAddress_City' => $Invoice->getChildDataAt('InvoiceRet ShipAddress City'),
                'ShipAddress_State' => $Invoice->getChildDataAt('InvoiceRet ShipAddress State'),
                'ShipAddress_PostalCode' => $Invoice->getChildDataAt('InvoiceRet ShipAddress PostalCode'),
                'BalanceRemaining' => $Invoice->getChildDataAt('InvoiceRet BalanceRemaining'),
                );

            QuickBooks_Utilities::log(QB_QUICKBOOKS_DSN, 'Importing invoice #' . $arr['RefNumber'] . ': ' . print_r($arr, true));

            foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
            {
                $arr[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
            }

            // Store the invoices in MySQL
            mysql_query("
                REPLACE INTO
                    qb_example_invoice
                (
                    " . implode(", ", array_keys($arr)) . "
                ) VALUES (
                    '" . implode("', '", array_values($arr)) . "'
                )") or die(trigger_error(mysql_error()));

            // Remove any old line items
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM qb_example_invoice_lineitem WHERE TxnID = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($arr['TxnID']) . "' ") or die(trigger_error(mysql_error()));

            // Process the line items
            foreach ($Invoice->children() as $Child)
            {
                if ($Child->name() == 'InvoiceLineRet')
                {
                    $InvoiceLine = $Child;

                    $lineitem = array( 
                        'TxnID' => $arr['TxnID'], 
                        'TxnLineID' => $InvoiceLine->getChildDataAt('InvoiceLineRet TxnLineID'), 
                        'Item_ListID' => $InvoiceLine->getChildDataAt('InvoiceLineRet ItemRef ListID'), 
                        'Item_FullName' => $InvoiceLine->getChildDataAt('InvoiceLineRet ItemRef FullName'), 
                        'Descrip' => $InvoiceLine->getChildDataAt('InvoiceLineRet Desc'), 
                        'Quantity' => $InvoiceLine->getChildDataAt('InvoiceLineRet Quantity'),
                        'Rate' => $InvoiceLine->getChildDataAt('InvoiceLineRet Rate'), 
                        );

                    foreach ($lineitem as $key => $value)
                    {
                        $lineitem[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
                    }

                    // Store the lineitems in MySQL
                    mysql_query("
                        INSERT INTO
                            qb_example_invoice_lineitem
                        (
                            " . implode(", ", array_keys($lineitem)) . "
                        ) VALUES (
                            '" . implode("', '", array_values($lineitem)) . "'
                        ) ") or die(trigger_error(mysql_error()));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

**3. Make sure that every time the Web Connector connects, you automatically send it that query to get those new invoices.**

Register a hook like this:

```
// An array of callback hooks
$hooks = array(
    QuickBooks_WebConnector_Handlers::HOOK_LOGINSUCCESS => '_quickbooks_hook_loginsuccess',     // call this whenever a successful login occurs
    );
```

That always queues up a request to get invoices:

```
function _quickbooks_hook_loginsuccess($requestID, $user, $hook, &$err, $hook_data, $callback_config)
{  
    $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_IMPORT_INVOICE, 1, QB_PRIORITY_INVOICE);
}
```

You'll want to make sure to look at the example I linked above for a few of the helper functions if you're going to re-use the code I pasted above.

If you have trouble, please POST YOUR CODE so we can see what you're tried so far.